# TCP Sequence Number

Tags: tcp, numbers, sequence, rfc

I'm trying to understand how the sequence numbers of the TCP header are generated.

In some places I read that it is the "index of the first byte in the packet" ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672734/tcp-sequence-number-question)), on some other sites it is a random 32bit generated number that is then incremented.

I don't really know which is which, so here are some questions:

- How is the initial sequence number generated? (Please provide an RFC number if there is one)
- How is it incremented?
- How is the secret key generated?

I read some of the RFCs like [RFC 6528](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6528#section-2), [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793), and [RFC 1948](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/rfc/rfc1948.txt) but I can't seem to understand which one is actually implemented.

I read about the "std" status but still...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which implementation? What about the source of that implementation are you specifically asking about?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I meant when you browse on Internet (HTTP/TCP/IP) what does your computer uses to generate those sequence numbers ? How does it work ?

Comment: So this isn't a programming question at all?

Comment: Well no, it's more of a "theoretical" / networking question.

Comment: it would be relevant if you wanted to decode a TCP stream yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TCP: How are the seq / ack numbers generated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692880/tcp-how-are-the-seq-ack-numbers-generated)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Each endpoint of a TCP connection establishes a starting sequence number for packets it sends, and sends this number in the SYN packet that it sends as part of establishing a connection.

There is no *requirement* for either end to follow a particular procedure in choosing the starting sequence number.  The operating system is free to use any mechanism it likes, but generally it's best if it chooses a random number, as this is more secure.

From that starting point, each packet sent by either end contains two sequence numbers - one to specify where in the stream the packet is, and an ACK sequence number which signifies the number of bytes *received*.  Both numbers are offset by the starting sequence number.

Read all about it in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) of course - look for "sequence number" in that page to get all the gory details.

Comment: Ah thank you for your quick answer ! =D I understand it better know. Just two follow-up question ^^ : Do you know how the random number is generated ? and Do you know to which RFC number the procedure you explained corresponds ? Thx again !

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek as explained, the initial sequence number can be chosen by _any_ method, although for best security it should be chosen using a good random number generator.  The SYN and ACK sequence number stuff is all in the core RFC 793 document.

Comment: That's not entirely true. While any ISN generation method can be used, RFC 793 proposes one algorithm in section 3.3. However, this has been subsequently criticized, and you correctly identified RFC 6528 which proposes a more robust one as the new standard. It obsoletes RFC 1948 by making the proposal intended for formal standardization rather than simply informational, but they (6528 and 1948) say basically the same things.

Answer (score 2):

In 4.4BSD (and most Berkeley-derived implementations) when the system is initialized the initial send sequence number is initialized to 1. This practice violates the Host Requirements RFC. (A comment in the code acknowledges that this is wrong.) This variable is then incremented by 64,000 every half-second, and will cycle back to 0 about every 9.5 hours. (This corresponds to a counter that is incremented every 8 microseconds, not every 4 microseconds.) Additionally, each time a connection is established, this variable is incremented by 64,000.

Answer (score 0):

It's a random number between 0 and 4,294,967,295. But in wireshark tool you can see syn as 0 (because it uses relative display) however you can make it to show original seq number by  doing Edit -> Preferences. and un-checking relative sequence numbers and window scaling under TCP protocol preferences. The next Sequence number would get increment based on the ACK number (a) that is received (becomes a + 1). ACK get increased based on the payload len (l) that it received (becomes l + 1). Note no data/payload is sent during SYN/FIN flag being active (does making the ACK increment by only one during SYN and FIN).